# Using ECDSA.sol to Sign smartcontract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, smart-contract-wallets

I'm in need of help using Lib ECDSA.
What am I trying to do?
I'm trying to get a subscription and check my Smart Contract if everything is ok.

Below I'm putting my files that I have so far.

When I run the tests it is entering the "else" condition, shouldn't it enter the IF condition? or am i using recover with the wrong parameters?

Would they be able to help me?

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "./TokenERC20.sol";

contract InstanceCoin{

    address contractInstance;

    constructor(address _contract){
        contractInstance = _contract;
    }

    function reedemToken(uint _amount, bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature) public {
        // TokenERC20 token = TokenERC20(contractInstance);
        if(ECDSA.recover(_hash, _signature) == msg.sender)
            revert("is correct");
        else 
            revert("is not correct"); //revert just test
    }
}
```

My file.js

```
const InstanceCoin = artifacts.require('coins/InstanceCoin');
const EthCrypto = require("eth-crypto");

const signerIdentity = EthCrypto.createIdentity();
const message = EthCrypto.hash.keccak256 ([ 
    {type: "uint256", value: "500"},     
  ]);
const signature = EthCrypto.sign(signerIdentity.privateKey, message);

console.log(`message: ${message}`);
console.log(`signature: ${signature}`);
console.log(`signer public key: ${signerIdentity.address}`);

contract("InstanceCoin", (accounts) => {    
    let [alice, bob, cain, dan] = accounts;
    let contractInstance;
    beforeEach(async () => {        
        contractInstance = await InstanceCoin.deployed();              
    });
    describe("deploys", async () => {
        it("just only test", async () => {
            await contractInstance.reedemToken(10, message, signature, {from: alice});
        });
    });
})
```

Output test:

```
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert is not correct -- Reason given: is not correct.
```

Comment: You are generating a signature matching the address of signerIdentity, But then you send that same signature using {from: alice}. It must fail as alice's address will not match a recover from signature.

Comment: @Hroussile but do i need to generate a private subscription for alice then? it is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little:

Simple contract validating the the signature matches the msg.sender, if not : revert.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

contract Recover{

    function reedemToken(uint _amount, bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature) public view {
        // TokenERC20 token = TokenERC20(contractInstance);
        if(ECDSA.recover(_hash, _signature) != msg.sender) {
            revert("Signature does not match message sender");
        } 
    }
}
```

And a simple test file :

```
const Recover = artifacts.require('Recover');
const EthCrypto = require("eth-crypto");

// Taken from ganache-cli : private key of the first account : accounts[0]
// Change it to match your private key
const privateKey = "0xce15d9e0330b9570ac1f5b9240717ad2c175f077632a699802767314f15a9205";


const publicKey = EthCrypto.publicKeyByPrivateKey(privateKey);
const address = EthCrypto.publicKey.toAddress(publicKey);

const message = EthCrypto.hash.keccak256 ([{type: "uint256", value: "500"},]);
const signature = EthCrypto.sign(privateKey, message);

let contractInstance;

console.log(`message: ${message}`);
console.log(`signature: ${signature}`);
console.log(`signer public key: ${publicKey}`);
console.log(`signer address ${address}`);

contract("Recover", (accounts) => {
    
    beforeEach(async () => {        
        contractInstance = await Recover.deployed();              
    });

    describe("Validate ECDSA contract behavior", async () => {
        it("Verifies that the message is signed by accounts[0]", async () => {
            await contractInstance.reedemToken(10, message, signature, {from: accounts[0]});
        });

        it("Verifies that the message was NOT signed by accounts[0]", async () => {
            await contractInstance.reedemToken(10, message, signature, {from: accounts[1]});
        });
    });
})
```

As you can see if you run the tests :

test 1 succeed because account[0] private key was used to sign the message. And account[0] is the message sender, so the address recovery matches msg.sender.

test 2 fails because msg.sender is accounts[1]. Which is definitely not a match with account[0] recovered from the message and signature on the contract side.

To generate a signature for Alice, you need to sign the message with Alice's private key. There is no other way. Only the private key holder can sign a message that authenticates him/her.

Think of the Recovery operation as validating that the person who sent you this message has the address X **and holds the private key associated with it**.